# Routes Address Issue in Broker Service

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, service-broker

While I was configuring Broker Service on the Customer site. I faced a confusing problem with the Route Address. The customer has a SQL Default instance and a named instance as below:
ADDRESS = N'TCP://SQLInst/SQLNamed1:4882'

I tried to Command Shell the DB to get the IP so work around the issue, but could only get the Default Instance IP
I used below link.

So what is the solution to this issue

Answer (score 1):

The syntax that you should be using is:

N'TCP://SQLInst:4882'

You are sending it to a server name and a specific TCP port which is being listened to by the SQL Server instance so that instance name isn't used in the connection.

Comment: Yeah I tried so, but when I try to verify configuration using SSBDiagnose. A message shown tells me that my user can't connect to SQLInst. Also the default instance has SQL 2008 SP3 and the named instance has SQL 2008 R2 SP1.
We tried to use ports.
Let's say default instance has port 11812 and named instance has 11912. So I'll use the ip and try the above ports. but when I defined the Endpoint to listen to the named instance port. Users were blocked to connect to the instance. Seems that Endpoint blocked any activity to that port.
Is is better to just use a simple named instance?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues accessing a SQL Server instance by name, you need to enable SQLServer browser enable on the client

Comment: I don't think this is the problem Diego.
The Address syntax itself doesn't accept the mentioned example or I am missing something.
Check MSDN link below
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186742.aspx

ADDRESS ='next_hop_address'
Specifies the network address for this route. The next_hop_address specifies a TCP/IP address in the following format:

    TCP://{ dns_name | netbios_name | ip_address } : port_number